# Why some large projects compile to small assemblies?

Tags: c#, .net

For instance, the last release of the famous library HtmlAgilityPack source is something like 110 000 lines of C#, and the assembly is 132 KB.

https://www.openhub.net/p/htmlagilitypack

My project is about 6500 lines and compiles to 300 KB assembly.

I haven't looked extensively at the source, but it is clearly not 100K loc usable classes. So what is that enormous amount of code doing?

Comment: because HtmlAgilityPack its just a huge amount of #comment? :P , ok nice question

Comment: Are you comparing debug and release build sizes?

Comment: Assembly size is not just due to # of lines of code (look at embedded resources, for example).

Comment: You're asking the wrong question. The real question is: _"What can inflate an assembly's size?"_, and the answer is _"Many things"_.

Comment: Not all lines of code are equal!

Comment: It depends on what type of project you write. Just a few hints:

* Winforms or Console
* References (only using them, or are they included?)
* Ressources

If you describe your project (and settings) a little more, I could tell you exactly why.

Comment: It is just C# code, though I didn't tought about unit tests, there is a point in that

Comment: Think about it the other way - "Look how much functionality I got from only 6,500 lines of code!"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition to differences such as debug vs release mode, etc., I suspect that comparing your 6,500 lines to the "110,000" lines in their source is misleading.

Lines of code is a quirky metric.  If you look at the [breakdown by language](https://www.openhub.net/p/htmlagilitypack/analyses/latest/languages_summary), you see that there are only about 55 KLOC in C# *for all projects* (only one of which is the actual Agility Pack assembly), much of which is (I suspect) braces and other "whitespace" that does not *directly* get represented in the binaries.  Also, just browsing through it, it does not use a lot of automatically-implemented properties, which use less *lines of code* for the same functionality.  For example:

```
internal int _lineposition;

public int LinePosition
{
    get
    {
        return this._lineposition;
    }
    internal set
    {
        this._lineposition = value;
    }
}
```

versus

```
public int LinePosition {get; internal set;}
```

12 lines of code versus 1 *for the same amount of compiled code*.

All that to say that there are a lot of caveats to using lines of code as a metric for the "size" of a program.

Comment: And yet, back in 2008 the library was 8500 lines, I guess it had quite the same functionality as it does now

Answer (score -2):

It may come from debug information in your code. It depends too if you make systems library calls (reduce size) or use a lot of your own written libraries.

Comment: This is not an answer to the question asked, and should not be posted as one. It would make a fine comment to the original question, but you've not yet earned the privilege of commenting. You cannot use the answer space to bypass not having that privilege, however. The space marked *Your Answer* is for specifically that (and only that) use - posting your answer to the question.